# Filesystem of swap space

Tags: filesystems, swap

What is the name of the filesystem used for swap space?

Comment: Which operating system? Windows is different from Linux, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, for Unix and Linux, swap is not a filesystem because it does not contain files, file metadata, and/or a file directory hierarchy. What swap is, is a memory mapped area of disk. That memory mapped area of disk might be a partition, or a file, but within it are not files, but pages.

For Linux, a swap partition on a PC formatted hard disk has a partition ID of 82. Once mkswap is run on it, the area inside is identified by having the text "SWAP_SPACE" or "SWAPSPACE2" in the last 10 bytes of the first page (usually 512 bytes).

If a file is used, the internal structure is the same, but the file should be created without any holes (unfragmented). The dd command is used for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can read some notes about the makeup of the swap file here:

http://linux.die.net/man/8/mkswap

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the OS, the swap space isn't a file system as it doesn't contain files in the first place but pages. It isn't either structured hierarchically, if at all, like most filesystems are.

Answer (score -1):

The name of file system is **swap**.Have a nice day....